# Copy tables from one database to another database but with different users, php in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm working on joomla plugin that could help me with backups of my site.

I have problem with copying database of one site to another. Both databases have different users. I tried to use query like that:

`INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM another_database.old_table`

Unfortunately I got an error:

`SELECT command denied to user 'user_old'@'ip' for table 'old_table'`

I understand an error, but I cant create another user that could have priviliges to both databases.

Can I somehow work this out in php? I create connection to both databases, but is there a way of doing this other than

`SELECT * FROM old_table`

then inserting all data fetched to new_table?

I would like to not use mysqldump because I want to have control which tables I will copy.

Comment: Unless you have Read/Write priviledges on both databases, you can not initiate actions on both databases with one query

Comment: Using MySQLDump allows you to specify which databases and/or tables to dump.

Comment: Maybe there is a way of 'putting' login and password that query should use when selecting data from another database. For example something like this : 'INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM login@password:another_database.old_table'

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqldump to get all the tables, load that sql file into the new database and then run:

```
DROP TABLE <table_name>;
```

on all the tables you do not want in the new database.